# How to resolve Cross-Dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependencies

I'm having hard times trying to resolve cross-dependency between the projects in one solution.
The solution it's an asp.net application that has several projects.

The web project consumes the services of a sessionwrapper class in the SLN.Core project.
Declared like:

```
public sealed class SW
{
    public static tblUserRow User
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null) return null;
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["dtUser"] == null ? null : (tblUsersRow)(HttpContext.Current.Session["dtUser"] as tblUsers).Rows[0];
        }
    }

    public static void User_Load(string userId)
    {
        tblUsers users = new tblUsers();
        users.LoadByID(userId);
        if (users.Count != 0)
        {
           HttpContext.Current.Session["dtUser"] = users;
        }
    }
}
```

The tblUserRow is part of the model definition of the users class (Strong typed datatable) in a separate models project. There are some other methods in the SW class, but aren't relevant.
So in SLN.Web I can access the user data like "SW.User.Name"

The models project is composed by the structures (model classes) and the DB engine classes in two different namespaces.

As seen above, the SW class depends on the models to declare User.
Up to here it's all OK.

But the fact is that model objects, need the User, Company, etc data when the classes are first created so they can get the default values. F.Ex: If you create a new invoice, it's nice to get the user (customer) assigned warehouse or payment type.

And as per working requeriments, the DB engine needs company or user data for making things like getting the DB (one per company) or saving log entries with user info.

Until the day that objects where passed on every call to DB engine classes or even methods, but now I'm refactoring this and I thought It would be cleaner and less memory consuming if that info could be got directly on the respective places from SW.

But there is cross-dependency between them. And as the SW members are declared static, so they can persist indepentent from session, I can't make an interface.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** There was an issue with the scope of the user data that was previously solved, so I corrected here.
Also I'll add some more code for better understanding. From here VB, sorry dudes, but that's a nice model of diversity.

Example of the tblUser model in SLN.Models:

```
<DesignerCategory("Code"), System.SerializableAttribute()>
Partial Public Class tblUsers
    Inherits TypedTableBase(Of tblUsersRow)

    <DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        BeginInit()
        InitClass()
        EndInit()
    End Sub

    <DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>
    Private Sub InitClass()
        TableName = TABLE_NAME

        With Columns
            .Add(New DataColumn(FIELD_ID, GetType(String)))
            .Add(New DataColumn(FIELD_Name, GetType(String)))
            ...
            'Added that last columns as example
            .Add(New DataColumn(FIELD_Company, GetType(String)) With {.DefaultValue=SW.Company.ID})
            .Add(New DataColumn(FIELD_Warehouse, GetType(String)) With {.DefaultValue=SW.Company.Warehouse})
        End With

        Dim keys(1) As DataColumn
        keys(0) = Columns(0)
        PrimaryKey = keys
    End Sub
...

    <DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>
    Public Sub LoadByID(Id As String)
        Rows.Clear()
        Merge(New SLN.DBEngine.Generic(SW.Company.Connection, doLog:=False).ExecuteQuery(COMMAND_LOADBY_ID, Id))
    End Sub
...
End Class
Partial Public Class tblUsersRow
    Inherits DataRow
    <DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>
    Friend Sub New(ByVal builder As DataRowBuilder)
        MyBase.New(builder)
    End Sub

    <DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>
    Public Property ID() As String
        Get
            Return DirectCast(MyBase.Item(0), String)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.Item(0) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return DirectCast(MyBase.Item(1), String)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.Item(1) = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ...
End Class
```

**Model classes are like this while I get a solution on EF for multiple DB. They where plain datatables.

Yes, there's another model class named Company that is also used in SW to provide company's data in session (multiple users, multiple companies logged onto)
You can see that on user construction, default values could be retrieved from SW. Same for other models like invoice heads, per example. That's the behaviour I want. By now all models that get default values, they get a complete object as a parameter of New(). Some models only want one field from a +25 flds object.
Also they use DBEngine for loading/querying/saving/deleting data.

In SLN.Web something like this may be seen (login):

```
SW.Company_Load(ddlCompany.Text)
sDescription = New Generic(SW.Company.Connection,False).ExecuteQuery("sp_Warehouse_LoadBy_Id",SW.User.Warehouse).Rows(0)("rDescription").ToString
```

Thaaats a roough example.

So SLN.Core.SW needs SLN.Models.tblUsersRow and SLN.DBEngine.Generic

And SLN.Models.tblUsers needs SLN.DBEngine but would also like to get SLN.Core.SW
...

SLN.DBEngine... needs SLN.Core.SW so he knows the DB to point to (some other things)

And SLN.Web need all of them. (sigh!)

Clear? (Errr...)

Comment: If _currentUser is static, it will be shared between all threads/requests and there will be only one current user in the entire system. Is that what you're really meaning to do?

Comment: Yes, that was a testing/initial version for the object. It's corrected to exclusively use session. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the cross dependecy by moving the data entity classes related to those in SW class to the same CORE project.
Also moved the DB access engine classes to CORE, so in the models project there are only the entities and it can depend on CORE for DB access.
The CORE project does not depend on anything, as all it's entities are on it and also has the DB access engine.

So finally it was another problem of bad estructure design.

I also would like to give credit to Fendy, because the answer was agood one in other scenario.
@Fendy if you know a way for giving you credit, please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Upvote will be enough. If my answer does not specifically answer your question, the upvote will be enough. And please comment at my answer for explanation so other user will not find it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand your story clearly. But from what I get, your model need current_user to create objects (well, I don't get the business logic why this is required), and your web sln need the model for current_user.

Basically, the flow should be like this:

- User class is defined
- current_user is initiated
- using the current_user, the model will initiate other objects

There are many ways available to accomplish this, however I propose 2 solution:

1. This implemenatation is to be done assuming you do dependency injection. Clean, and testable. This design is for Model solution.

   ```
   public interface IUserProvider
   {
       User CurrentUser { get; }
   }

   public class ModelCreator
   {
       public ModelCreator(IUserProvider provider)
       {
           this.provider = provider;
       }
       IUserProvider provider;

       public Invoice Get(){
           User currentUser = provider.CurrentUser;
           // do other
       }
   }
   ```
2. This implementation is to be done without dependency injection. Not clean, but mockable and easy to design. This design is for Model or Entity solution.

   ```
   public static class UserProvider
   {
       private static Func<User> currentUserDelegate = new Func<User>(NullUser);
       public static Func<User> CurrentUserDelegate
       {
           set
           {
               currentUserDelegate = value;
           }
       }

       private static User NullUser()
       {
           return null;
       }
       public static User CurrentUser
       {
           get
           {
               return currentUserDelegate();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   The usage:

   ```
   public sealed class SW
   {
       private static User _currentUser;
       public static User GetCurrentUser()
       {
           if (_currentUser == null)
           {
               tblUsers users = new tblUsers();
               users.LoadByID(userId);
               HttpContext.Current.Session["dtUser"] = users;
               _currentUser = users[0];
           }
           return _currentUser;
       }

       public static void User_Load(string userId)
       {
           UserProvider.CurrentUserDelegate = new Func<User>(GetCurrentUser);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I'm so sorry that I wasn't more clear. While I study your example, I must say that interfaces aren't allowed for static classes or methods. (that's the problem) I may correct the code with the later version so you can see the latest declarations.

Comment: It will be better if you can provide the general structure in code based than described in story. Such as you stated that `these are the classes in Model, and these are in UI`

Comment: Gave an upvote for that answer because after trying this approach and finding it completely valid, I realized that was not applicable in my scenario. But It would be a good solution when reorganizing is not possible, as my question suggested.